# Make webserver handle page refresh/bookmarks like Vue dev server

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm writing a Vue/Nuxt app. When I use the development server ("yarn dev" -> localhost:3000), page refreshes work great. I can navigate to any page in my app, refresh the browser, and the page loads fine.

When I generate the app into the /dist folder and then serve it as static pages from a regular web server, page refreshes cause a server-generated 404 error. For example, I can go to /signin, click Forgot Password to go to /forgotpassword, and then reload the page. Works fine at dev time, fails in production.

The generated app has a /forgotpassword directory, and that contains an index.html. When I go straight to /forgotpassword/index.html the production server does load it. (Although it's case-sensitive, unlike the dev server, and it redirects to /signin. I'm not sure why, but it might not be relevant to the question.)

Also, when I go to a bad url, the dev server returns a Vue/Nuxt 404 page, and the production server returns a server-generated one.

I want to make my production web server work just like the dev server. The production server is written in Java and I have a lot of control over how it works.

So, what changes do I need to make in the production server to make it behave?

**Update**
Ok, so part of the answer is to enable welcome files in subfolders. But somehow the dev server displays client-side 404 pages when there is a bad URL. How does that happen?

Comment: Um, hello? Don't downvote without giving a reason why.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the router in `History` mode, you should set your server to serve the app accordingly. You can find both configurations for NGINX or APACHE in the [**router docs**](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode)

**Apache**

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /
>   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

and for **nginx**:

> ```
> nginx
> location / {
>   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
> }
> ```

Comment: Could you explain what this does, exactly?

Comment: It just tells your server how to interpret the URL, where to look for. In the nginx case as example it check for existing files using two different structures based on the Uri. Else it uses the index as fallback. That&#39;s why using this setup you don't have a 404 on refresh. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. It appears that this just enables welcome files in subfolders. That's helpful, but not the whole answer.